# can't trigger onclick event

Tags: jquery, events, onclick

I have an onclick event in my index.html file related to a function :

```
<div class="text-center"><div class="btn btn-success expand20" onclick="expand()">Agrandir à 20</div></div>
```

My minesweeper.js file is linked in the html like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="minesweeper.js"></script>
```

My function expand.js is defined in minesweeper.js :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    function expand() {
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            $("table").append("<tr><td class='unopened'></td><td class='unopened'></td></tr>");
        }
    }
});
```

Jquery is included at the end of my html file :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However when I click on button I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: expand is not defined

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you included JQuery CDN?

Comment: Place the code in the head section, also put it outside Document ready handler.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){});` is jQuery..so if you not loading the library before the code executes you are bound to get the error message. You can also work by assigning the function to `window.onload = function(){ //your code here}` or `window.onload = expand();` you should also avoid adding JS event handlers in html, use JS selectors and apply the event only after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that event handlers in the DOM are trying to access functions available in the global scope.

Since you are defining the function expend inside a closure (an anonymous function called on jQuery ready) the function gets defined in that scope but not in the global scope.

Also, defining functions like that does not require to wait for domReady... I suggest you move the declaration outside that event handler, and only use it to actually do something.